# Retina iPad Simulator display issue?

Tags: ipad, simulator, retina-display

I'm making a retina iPad app.  When I test with iPad simulator I get a nice display of my icons and buttons etc...

But when I switch to the retina simulator I get big buttons and images... Is that normal? Unfortunately I haven't a real iPad to test on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is normal.

The reason being is the resolution of the retina display is 2048x1536 while the regular iPad is 1024x768.

When you test your app in the regular simulator, you'll see your app in 1024x768, which will appear "regular sized" on your display.  When you test your app in the retina simulator, you'll be seeing your app in the full 2048x1536 resolution.  And since chances are very good your computer monitor is not a retina display, you'll see it a bigger window with scaled up UI elements.

If you test your app on an iPad with a retina display you'll see everything is the same size as on a non retina iPad, since the physical screen size is the same.

Comment: The resolution of the *screen* is 2048x1536 pixels. The number of coordinates on the display is 1024x768. The system uses 1/2 points to display a pixel, which is why it all works--the system scales `@2x` graphics down by 50% which lands odd pixels in the graphics on 1/2 points. An important distinction.